# Where is Linux Kernel Boot Arguments parsed

Tags: linux-kernel, command-line-arguments

I am playing around with a Android Linux kernel. The kernel is the P970 V30B kernel. Available [here](http://www.lg.com/global/support/opensource/opensource-detail.jsp?detailCustomerModelCode=LGP970).I want to find out what a specific cmdline argument does exactly.

I know it's commandline arguments and there's one argument that is included that I can't find what exactly it does. It's not a standard commandline argument (I can't find any documentation on it) and I suspect it's specific to this kernel. I want to find out what that specific cmdline argument does exactly.

The best reference I was able to find on the subject is [this](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/bootparam.7.html). This told me where about it parses the arguments, but it didn't have enough detail for what I wanted to to find out.

I've looked at the source for the commandline parsing, but it jump around alot and I can't find where it actually parses the individual commands.

I'm looking for a way to get where it parses the command argument. I've tried various fgrep commands to look for a string containing the parameter as a starting point, but to no avail.

Any help or pointers on the subject will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the file cmdline.c

http://lxr.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/#linux/lib/cmdline.c

You have there the functions get_option(), get_options() etc.

They should be used where the actual parameters are read and dispatched.

edit: The actual parsing is in the file main.c

http://lxr.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/#linux/init/main.c

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Using "fgrep -r get_option *" I was able to get where it was being used.